# is there a way to capture certain portions of a camera android

Tags: android, camera

I have been doing some research on capturing image from camera and cropping the image. But I want to capture the already cropped image. That is I want to capture only portions of the whole camera image. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Can you please show us the code which you have tried? Please don't expect others to write full code for you. Hire a freelancer for that job. Here users volunteer to help other users when they are stuck on a specific programming related problem.

Answer (score 1):

No.  But capturing the whole image and cropping after should be fine, there's nothing you can't do later that you could do when taking the image, so far as cropping goes.